# Efficient way to find prefix in coma separated list of prefixes

Tags: php

I have a prefix stored in a variable

```
$prefix = “07”;
```

And coma separated list of prefixes stored in another variable (the list is provide by user using text box)

```
$allPrefixes = “07,03,+17”;
```

What is efficient way to check if the value stored in $prefix is one of the prefixes stored in $allPrefixes

Comment: As arrays in PHP are associative, simply splitting a list into an array keys will be equivalent to using a hashset in another language.

Comment: @AntonSamsonov looks like he's using a string for `$allPrefixes`. Or Syed, do you control this (so an array can be used as Anton suggests?

Comment: If only the original containers (two strings) should be used and no other object is allowed to be created, then the task seems unsolvable otherwise to using `strpos()` and doing word-boundary test (or `preg_match()` with properly written regular expression, but that would be slower).

Comment: The value stored in $allPrefixes is coming from users using a text box on html page,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go for a regex to match:

```
$regex = "/(^|,)".$prefixe."(,|$)/";
preg_match($regex,$allPrefixes);
```

- On beginning of string before a comma,
- between commas or
- after comma, at end of string

The above regex will match, for example, `07` but not `007`.

*General knowledge, not applicable in this case:

If `007` is not likely to appear, or `prefixe` is not likely to be a substring of any other `prefixe`, then you can use `strpos($allPrefixes, $prefixe) > -1` instead, which is quite more efficient.*

**However**
wrapping the `$allPrefixes` string between `,` and using strpos might be both efficient and accurate:

```
strpos(",".$allPrefixes.",", ",".$prefixe.",")
```

will match 07 but not 007

Comment: Thank you for answer, in my given example 07 must mach 07 not 007, I think 'preg_match' is batter to use instead of 'strpos'

Comment: In that case, I will degrade the part of `strpos`. The regex is ready to use as you want it.

Comment: What about using `$prefixesArray = preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', $allPrefixes, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);` and then checking 
`in_array($prefixe, $array);`

Comment: That would not be efficient. There are countless right ways to do this.

Comment: What will be the result of your provided solution if I have these two values in variables
`$prefixe = “”;` and 
`$allPrefixes = “07,”;` check it carefully there is coma at the end of 07

Comment: Empty prefix? Not provided in this solution. But if prefixe is 07, there will be much. You can always test your results and try things

Comment: Tell me last thing before I accept your answer, what changes will be need in your provided solution if I need to look for number i.e. `$prefixe = 7;` in `$allPrefixes = “7,3,17”;`

Comment: No changes at all. You are injecting a variable in a string, so it will become string in this line: `$regex = "/(^|,)".$prefixe."(,|$)/";`